# prevent default on keydown of spacebar regarding scroll down without affecting text inputs

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, preventdefault

I don't want the space-bar to cause the page to scroll. 
but I want to work as expected inside of an input or a content-editable div.

I have tried something like this but the page still scrolls down

```
$(document).on('keydown', function (e) {
        var $target = $(e.originalEvent.target);
        if (!$target.closest('[contenteditable="true"]') && !$target.closest('input')){
            e.preventDefault();
        }
    });
```

Comment: My suspicion is that you bind to each editable field's "onfocus" event. If none of the text fields have focus, then `preventDefault` to your heart's content :)

Comment: great idea. I will try it using document.activeElement to check if the focus is on an editable field, and post the answer here if it works :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example of getting the focused element, checking for input or contenteditable and the space key. Preventing the default action if your condition is not met.

```
$(document).on("keypress", function(e) {
    var $focusElem = $(":focus");
    if(e.which == 32 && !($focusElem.is("input") || $focusElem.attr("contenteditable") == "true"))
        e.preventDefault();
});
```

Comment: did not helped in my case. page still jumps